# Tratamento especial para cadeia de caracteres, por quê?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Sei que arrays são elementos estáticos empregados quando se tem um tamanho pré-determinado que possa ser utilizado. Mas falando da inicialização, quando o tamanho já está estabelecido ao lado do array, gostaria saber, essencialmente o porquê de não se poder utilizar outros tipos de arrays como utilizam-se cadeias de caracteres em C (notação de ponteiro). Por exemplo eu posso escrever:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
   char *sstring = "Olá, Mundo!";

   char schars[] = {'O', 'l', 'a', '\0'};

   int mnumbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

   printf("Sstring : %s\n", sstring); 
   printf("Schars : %s\n", schars);
   printf("Mnumber : %d\n", *mnumbers);

   return 0;
}
```

Mas em contrapartida não posso escrever:

```
char *sstring = "Olá, Mundo!";

char *schars = {'O', 'l', 'a', '\0'};

int *mnumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Mesmo que o tamanho seja conhecido, afinal eu estou inicializando os arrays. Por que isto acontece? Por que, mesmo em um array de chars inicializados com parenteses, não é possível o tratamento como ponteiros?

Isso ocorre inclusive com arrays e ponterios de dimensões maiores (obviamente):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int arrayInt[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

   char *arrayChar[] = {"PALAVRA", "teste", "HEY"};

   char **names = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));   

   *names = "Teste";
   *(names + 1) = "de";
   *(names + 2) = "Arrays";


   printf("%d\n", arrayInt[1][2]); 
   printf("%c\n", arrayChar[0][4]); 

   printf("Nome: %s %s %s\n", *names, *(names + 1), *(names + 2)); 

   return 0;
}
```

Não é possível fazer `int **arrayInt = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};` e ainda é necessário informar uma dimensão do array, mesmo declarando explicitamente ele. Uma forma mista `char *arrayChar[] = {"PALAVRA", "teste", "HEY"};` ainda é possível, mas `char *arrayChar[] = {{'O', 'l', 'a', '\0'}, {'M', 'u', 'n', 'd', 'o', '\0'}};` não. Parece que o uso de colchetes `[]` está ligada a inicialização com chaves `{}`. Queria saber a razão disso.

Comment: `{ }` são chaves. Parenteses: `( )` - mas é provavel que só tenha sido uma confusão na hora de escrever - quase um erro de digitação .

Comment: @jsbueno Obg.  Corrigido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta rápida é que sim, C tem tratamento especial para strings, "porque sim".

A resposta longa é que você está assumindo que vetores e ponteiros de C são totalmente intercambiáveis em C, o que não é verdade! O que ocorre é que em C é que em diversas ocasiões há uma conversão automática do vetor para um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento do vetor. Na sua pergunta, tem dois lugares que essa diferença aparece:

### 1) Você precisa de ter um vetor alocando a memória.

Strings em C são um caso especial. Quando você usa um literal de string o compilador C vai alocar um espaço de memória na área de dados (somente leitura) do executável. Ele também pode fazer otimizações como alocar dois literais de string de mesmo conteúdo em um único lugar.

Já para tipos que não são string e até mesmo para vetores mutáveis contendo caracteres, você vai precisar alocar um vetor em algum lugar para armazenar seus dados. O compilador C não vai botar eles em algum lugar especial pra você.

### 2) Ponteiro para ponteiro e vetor multidimensional não é a mesma coisa.

Tome como exemplo a matriz 3x3

```
int mat[3][3] = {
  00, 10, 20,
  30, 40, 50,
  60, 70, 80,
};
```

A representação disso em memória é um vetorzão de 9 elementos, com uma linha depois da outra.

```
mat --> [ 00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 ]
```

E quando você acessa `mat[i][j]`, o compilador pega o elemento `3*i + j` pra você. Repare que ele precisou saber o número de colunas em cada linha para poder fazer isso.

Já uma matriz usando int ** vai ter que ser armazenada de forma diferente.

```
// Acho que precisa de C99 pra compilar isso aqui.
// Mas se não rodar dá pra ter uma idéia...

int linhaA[] = {00, 10, 20};
int linhaB[] = {30, 40, 50};
int linhaC[] = {60, 70, 80};

int *linhas[3] = {linhaA, linhaB, linhaC};

int **mat = linhas; // Aqui ocorre um cast automático de tipo
```

Que na memória aparece como

```
mat --> [linhaA, linhaB, linhaC]
           |       |       |
           |       |       +-----> [60, 70, 80]
           |       +-------------> [30, 40, 50]
           +---------------------> [00, 10, 20]
```

Note que temos um vetor de ponteiros e que os dados não precisam estar num vetor só ou mesmo com as linhas em ordem. Para acessar `mat[i][j]` realmente só fazemos duas derreferencias uma após a outra.

No final das contas o que isso tudo significa é que um `int [3][3]` (vetor bidimensional 3x3 de inteiros) pode ser convertido automáticamente para um `int (*)[3]` (ponteiro para vetor de 3 inteiros) mas não pode ser convertido aumaticamente para `int **` (ponteiro para ponteiro de inteiros).  A raiz disso tudo é que quando usamos um vetor bidimensional o compilador precisa saber o tamanho de todas as dimensões do vetor (exceto a mais da esquerda -- o número de linhas) para poder acessar um elemento.

Comment: Então basicamente é "Strings em C são um caso especial. Quando você usa um literal de string o compilador C vai alocar um espaço de memória na área de dados (somente leitura) do executável. Ele também pode fazer otimizações como alocar dois literais de string de mesmo conteúdo em um único lugar" , pois o código assembly o faz assim?

Comment: Acho que tem mais a ver com as regras do C do que com o assembly. Mas sim, strings são um caso especial.

Comment: "o compilador precisa saber o tamanho de todas as dimensões + 'menos a última'  "

Comment: lembrando que "strings" sequer existem em C em tempo de execução: são só um vetor de bytes (ou de caractéres se você desprezar qualquer questão de codificação de texto, que não é correto nos dias de hoje). Mas todoo suporte da linguagem a strings está limitado a esses casos especiais em tempo de compilação, e a funções na biblioteca padrão que interpretam o byte com valor 0 numa sequência como o final da sequência. (estou escrevendo por que as vezes as pessoas não percebem que esse "terminado em '\x00' é uma convenção da biblioteca, e não uma determinação da linguagem)

Comment: Na verdade `int *linhas[] = {linhaA, linhaB, linhaC};` sem a largura de colunas funcionou em C99. Por que então não posso atribuir diretamente à **?

Comment: Tente declarar um vetor bidimensional sem especificar nenhuma dimensão -- `int foo[][]` -- e veja a mensagem de erro que você obtém. Como o jsbueno disse, quando se trata de vetores multidimensionais o compilador precisa saber todas as dimensões exceto a mais da esquerda. (Se você olhar a conta que precisa fazer pra pegar um elemento isso fica claro)